# Проблемы с отображение текста с применением Freemarker & Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, freemarker

При использовании Spring boot контроллера и Freemarkera, проблема с отображением текста на странице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот метод который возвращает view с добавлением элементов:

```
@GetMapping("/{pageNumber}")
public String getPageByNumber(Model model, @PathVariable int pageNumber) throws SQLException {
    employees = DataFactory.getEmployeesByPage(pageNumber);
    model.addAttribute("employeeId", "12332578645");
    return "pages/index.html";
}
```

Вот код pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ukeesTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>test</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.9-rc</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
      <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

А вот код Html страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/1">1</a>
            <a href="/2">2</a>
            <a href="/3">3</a>
            <a href="/4">4</a>
            <a href="/5">5</a>
            <a href="/6">6</a>
            <a href="/7">7</a>
            <a href="/8">8</a>
            <a href="/9">9</a>
            <a href="/10">10</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style="background: #808080">empID</th>
                    <th style="background: #808080">empName</th>
                    <th style="background: #808080">empActive</th>
                    <th>Dempdepartment</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="table-content">
                    <td><a href="">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
                    <td>${employeeId}</td>
                    <td>@{name}</td>
                    <td>@{empActive}</td>
                    <td>th:text="${department.depName}"</td>
                    <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href=""></a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">View</a></td>
                    <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="/1">1</a>
            <a href="/2">2</a>
            <a href="/3">3</a>
            <a href="/4">4</a>
            <a href="/5">5</a>
            <a href="/6">6</a>
            <a href="/7">7</a>
            <a href="/8">8</a>
            <a href="/9">9</a>
            <a href="/10">10</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ModelMap попробуйте

Comment: @GenCloud ModelMap тоже не работает, есть еще варианты?

Comment: Честно говоря, складывается впечатление, что фримаркер просто не подключен. Увидеть бы pom.xml и код html странички

Comment: @АндрейГалкин Я добавил в описание код html страницы и код pom.xml

Comment: @MainStar вы используете freemarker и thymeleaf, но необходимых стартеров в поме нет.

Comment: @aleshka-batman, о каких стартерах идет речь? Не совсем понял.